# Aplicar extensión en xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, rápido

quiero compartir una extensión muy interesante que encontre de un programador en youtube. Dicha extensión sirve para editar y personalizar los placeholder.

```
extension UIView {

/// set icon of 20x20 with left padding of 8px
func anchor (top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    if let top = top {
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
    }
    
    if let left = left {
        self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
    }
    
    if let bottom = bottom {
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
    }
    
    if let right = right {
        self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
    }
    
    if width != 0 {
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }
    
    if height != 0 {
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
}

func textContainerView(view: UIView, _ image: UIImage, _ textField: UITextField) -> UIView {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.alpha = 0.87
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.anchor (top:nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom:nil, right:nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft:8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 24, height:24)
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
    view.addSubview(textField)
    textField.anchor(top: nil, left: imageView.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)
    textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let separatorView = UIView()
    separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor (white: 1, alpha: 0.87)
    view.addSubview(separatorView)
    separatorView.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.75)
    return view
}
}
```

Sin embargo, en el momento de aplicar dicha extensión me encuentro con un pequeño dilema ya que siguiendo las guias del autor el cual solo programa en codigo (no usa storyboard), veo que es diferente a lo que he aprendido. Esta es la ejecución que habia planteado pero de una u otra manera el codigo me falla.

```
lazy var emailContainerView: UIView = {
let view = UIView()
return view.textContainerView(view: view, image, passwordTextField)}()

userNameTextField = emailContainerView as? UITextField
```

[image: En el momento de presionar login, el cual se ubican los placeholder con las atributos de la extensión, la aplicación se paraliza]

En el momento de presionar login, el cual se ubican los placeholder, la aplicación se para.

Agradezco el aporte que me puedan brindar y las personas que se pueden beneficiar de este contenido se que tambien estaran agradecidos con ustedes.

Comment: Mi amigo, cuando realizo la simulación con el proceso incluido se bloquea la aplicación.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta con una imagen de referencia. Muchas gracias....